# Should I Edit an Answer or Add a New Answer When One Becomes Outdated?

Tags: discussion, questions

When an answer becomes outdated, such as a question about something in an older YouTube or Gmail version, should I be editing a currently accepted answer or adding new answer?

There are two cases that need to be answered here:

1. Question has an already accepted answer
2. Question has answers though none are accepted yet

What should I be doing in these cases?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

In both cases it's probably best to provide a new answer detailing the current solution.

In the first case where there is an accepted answer I'd be tempted to leave a comment either on the answer or the question pointing out that it's now outdated. A comment on the question will alert the asker and allow them to change the accepted answer (if they want to). A comment on the answer will alert the answerer that their answer is now out of date.

Personally I wouldn't down-vote the answer - but you may have different ideas.